# Java doesn't delete file

Tags: java, file

Initially the function Attemps works fine for the first time, I elaborate the request in the file and move the content to the temporary file, then I delete the log file and rename the file "temporaneo.txt" in "log.txt".
If you start for the second time this function but it seems that the procedure doesn't have more success, particularly the log file is not deleted, and the file "temporaneo.txt" isn't renamed in "log.txt"
Why does this happen? I mistaken the procedure? I really can't deal with them, whereas the first time this function is performed going great.

```
public void Attemps()throws IOException
 {
   try 
   {
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log.txt"));
       PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("temporaneo.txt"));

       String line; 
       String params[]; 

       while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
       {
           params = line.split(";", 2);
            if(client.equals(params[0])) 
            { 
                int accessi_aggiornati = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                accessi_aggiornati--;
                params[1] = String.valueOf(accessi_aggiornati);
                out.print(params[0] + ";" + params[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                out.println(line); 
       }
    }
       in.flush(); //log
       out.flush(); //temporaneo
       in.close();
       out.close();

       //Delete log and rename temporary file
       File f1 = new File("log.txt");
       f1.delete();     
       File f2 = new File("temporaneo.txt");
       f2.renameTo(f1);

       System.out.println("Update complete");
   }catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: do you actually have this file? is it not null value?

Comment: log file is always there, I just use this code to update the content of the log.txt

Comment: Just so I understand completely, if you run this once, it works. But after that, it doesn't?

Comment: Yeah, the function works only for the first time. I also try to System.gc(); after the flow close, but unfortunately the problem's remain...

Comment: And no errors are thrown?

Comment: I'm having a really hard time why you create a new file and then immediately delete it.

Comment: have you checked the return value of f1.delete(); ? It is a boolean that should be true if the deletion is successful. You may also try: f2.renameTo(new File("log.txt")); to make sure you have a new instance of the File object.

Comment: Also `f1.delete();` and `f2.renameTo(f1);` return booleans. You could check them.

Comment: No erros thrown. This code eliminates log.txt because it contains old values, I update the values through the while loop, therefore they save in a temporary file which then will take the place of log.txt. I already tried with a Boolean variable and the first time returns true, while the second false.

Comment: I ran this code (minus the `if(client.equals(params[0])) ` part) and this ran fine for me.

Comment: The file is also updated the next time? I'm stuck on this problem for a week and I can not deal with them.

Comment: What I did was (1) Create log.txt with a value (2) Run the code using breakpoints (3) confirm that the values move (4) Change log.txt again with new values (5) Confirm it works again (6) Ran again and changed the temp file right after closing things out with a new value and see it in log.txt

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: How much time is going on between running this the first time and second time? It's weird, but you may have some kind of liveliness issue where you can't delete the file because your program still has that file open.

Comment: a few second... I've other BufferedReader that open the file but I close all after the open.

Answer (score 0):

1. BufferReader does not have flush() method.
2. The above code will not solve your purpose , becuase it is cyclic in nature

you are coping the content of log.txt file to temporaneo.txt--> then deleting log.txt file --> then renaming the temporaneo.txt name to log.txt

so, finally you have log.txt file with the same content .

Final code look like this:-

```
public void Attemps() {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "log.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("temporaneo.txt"));

        String line;
        String params[];

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
   {
       params = line.split(";", 2);
        if(client.equals(params[0])) 
        { 
            int accessi_aggiornati = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
            accessi_aggiornati--;
            params[1] = String.valueOf(accessi_aggiornati);
            out.print(params[0] + ";" + params[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            out.println(line); 
   }
}
        // in.flush(); // log
        out.flush(); // temporaneo
        in.close();
        out.close();

        // Delete log and rename temporary file
        File f1 = new File("log.txt");
        f1.delete();
        boolean isCreated = f1.createNewFile();

        System.out.println("Update complete=" + isCreated);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the same with this code, is so strange.

Answer (score -1):

BufferedReader doesn't know a method called "flush()" – neighter in Java 7 or 8.
Remove it and everything should work fine.

Comment: That is an issue, but the OP said they can run their code. I would imagine it wouldn't run if this was an error

Comment: Well, I'm sorry posting this as an answer but I can comment right now.

Comment: I would change to a comment before the chance of getting downvoted :-)